# Is there a way to change the order of text in a cell?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

There *has* to be a way to do this, but as a graphic designer, spreadsheet programs are not my forte.

I have 500+ cells of names written like this: "Davidson, Lauren O." and I need them to be "Lauren O. Davidson". Basically, everything left of the comma needs to be moved to the end of the string.

It doesn't even have to be kept in a LibreOffice Calc format - I just need to copy and paste the text into InDesign.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is a search/replace using regular expressions (in my example, i assume every name entry has a comma and a space after it to divide the surname and the given name/middle name initial):

1. Copy the cells holding the names to a new sheet (so there's no data loss if something goes wrong);
2. Open the "`Find & Replace`" dialogue using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or menu "`Edit`" -> "`Find & Replace ...`";
3. In the "`Search for`" input box, enter:

   > `(.*),\s(.*)`
4. In the "`Replace with`" input box, enter:

   > `$2 $1`
5. Open "`Other options`" and make sure that the "`Regular expressions`" option is enabled:

   [image]
6. Start the search/replace using <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.